# Popup div not in the middle of screen on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

I have two divs

```
<div class="one">contains a massive image with fixed height and width</div>
<div class="two">contains popup</div>

.one {
        background-image: url("image");
        background-position: left top; 
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-color: transparent;

        height:900px;
        width:1000px;

        margin:0 auto;
}

.overlay {
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    position:fixed;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    z-index:4;
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;

    }

    .popupwrapper{
        background:white;
        height: 100%;
        max-width: 300px;
        width: 100%;
        max-height: 320px;
        text-align: center;
        padding:3em;
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-top: 120px;

        //for small screens
        margin-left: 40px;  
    }
```

The problem I have is that, since the div "one" is a fixed size when I view it on mobile phone, the popup isn't actually displayed in the center of the screen but rather how it would be displayed on a laptop screen. I have tried fixing this with using margin left on small screen which centers the div in the middle of a mobile screen. However, when I scroll because the div has a margin-left it doesn't sit in the center as I scroll.

Additionally, this only seems to happen in Safari ( without the margin-left or fixed max-width the div seems to be huge on mobile screens) but in Chrome is fine?

Two questions:

1. How do I stop the div from scrolling? I have tried overflow but it still scrolls.
2. Is there a CSS hack for just Safari? I have tried many but none of them seem to work?

Comment: Have you used max-width:1000px

Comment: @GauravRai I have tried that it gets too big for mobile screens. For some reason when I use it in Chrome on my iPhone the popup is fitted perfectly to the iPhone screen but when I use it in Safari the popup is really zoomed in or something.

Comment: Safari Version 5.1+?

Comment: I guess the latest one on iOS 9.2. It also renders the font completely different Chrome... @GauravRai

Answer (score 0):

I understand from your question that you want to show a overlay that's always in the middel of the screen and on top of the rest.

If the size of the modal is fixed, then you can do it like this:

```
.one {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;

  margin: -450px 0 0 -500px;

  width: 1000px;
  height: 900px;
}
```

Example: [click](https://jsfiddle.net/b7fpo9c8/)

Only the size of the overlay is way to big for a mobile device.. Maybe use media queries to have a different size on mobile screens?

Comment: I have tried as you suggested but it still scrolls and not proportionate to the scrolling  :(  For some reason when I use it in Chrome on my iPhone the popup is fitted perfectly to the iPhone screen but when I use it in Safari the popup is really zoomed in or something.

Comment: You can control how mobile devices handles the rendering of your app. Here is more info about viewport meta's in mobile devices: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Answer (score 0):

1. May be height of any element is more than its actual height. That's why scrolling is coming.